# Creation of swift framework with story board and view

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode-storyboard, ios-frameworks

I am trying to create a framework with swift which has storyboard, view and view controllers etc. 
I have no idea how to do it in swift, Can anybody guide me through process or provide me a link to any article.

Thanks in advance.